# Inserting date into DB with date time picker

Tags: c#, date, datetimepicker

This is my first time working with date time picker in C#.
Below is my insert data user control. It adds all the data present in all the textboxes to DB.Neglect, but the order date and call date both are not functional.

[image]

The data type of the all the current dates in DB is 'date'.
When I run the program and insert and click the txtbox of current date it is autofilled with today's date [as programmed] but it is inserted in such format 'dd/mm/yyyy'.

But earlier when I used to manually enter date in the textbox the format would be 'yyyy-mm-dd'. Earlier it succeeded to insert the date into DB but now it doesn't.

I guess that is because of the format of the date and I am missing something in my code:

```
private bool insertdata()
        {
           //I've included the value of current date text box in string format which I think may be causing problem 
                string custname = txtcustname.Text, custcat = cmbcustcat.Text, date = txtdate.Text, phoneno = txtphoneno.Text, dresstype = cmbtype.Text, pattern = cmbpattern.Text, height = txtheight.Text, waist = txtwaist.Text, padar = txtpadar.Text, advance = txtadvance.Text;
                if (custname != null && custcat != null && date != null && phoneno != null && dresstype != null && pattern != null && height != null && waist != null && padar != null)
                {
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ordertbl(cust_name,cust_cat,date,phoneno,dress_type,pattern,height,waist,padar,adv) VALUES('" + custname + "','" + custcat + "','" + date + "','" + phoneno + "','" + dresstype + "','" + pattern + "','" + height + "','" + waist + "','" + padar + "','" + advance + "')", con);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    return true;
                }
                else 
                {
                    return false;
                }
           //this method is called in the add data button


        }
        private void calenderdate(TextBox txtbox)
        {
            //autofills textbox with current date...The drop down arrow beside the txtbox is the DTP and it is initially not visible.
            if (calcurrentdate.Visible == false)
            {
                calcurrentdate.Visible = true;
                txtbox.Text = calcurrentdate.Value.ToShortDateString();
            }
        }
private void txtdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //when the text box of currentdate is clicked it is auto filled with today's date
            calenderdate(txtdate);
        }
```

Comment: Date types in the database don't have a format, they are binary data. The format only applies when you show a date in a user interface. Use `SqlParameter`s and any formatting problems in your SQL will go away. Concatenating SQL strings is insecure and error prone.

Comment: Please do some research on how to parameterize your queries.. Not only is what you're doing **super** insecure, it's definitely going to cause you headaches.

Comment: @Crowcoder I did not understand what you just said. I am a very beginner and can you please tell this in a easier way ?

Comment: @BrootsWaymb yes It is Indeed causing me headaches I have started to do research on parameterizing